# syntax for putting column names into a package formula from a text string

Tags: r, dataframe, syntax

I am trying to make my input for a model dynamic by letting the user choose which parameters to use in R shiny interface.

The old static code looks like this:

```
randomForest(factor(carb) ~ mpg + cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars, ntree = 10, na.action = na.omit)
```

using the mtcars data set.

For the new version, the columns to use after the ~ will come from the UI interface choices will be a vector of the column names to use:

```
pars <-  c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp', 'hp')
```

How can I change the syntax of the `randomForest` equation so that it will run over the vector of pars, so that whatever the vector is it will run over the columns chosen by the user of the interface automatically on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.formula()` can help you with this.

```
frm <- as.formula(paste("factor(carb) ~ ", paste(pars, collapse= "+"))) 
frm
factor(carb) ~ mpg + cyl + disp + hp

randomForest(frm, data = mtcars, ntree = 10, na.action = na.omit)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = frm, data = mtcars, ntree = 10, na.action = na.omit) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 10
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 31.25%
Confusion matrix:
  1 2 3 4 6 8 class.error
1 5 0 0 2 0 0   0.2857143
2 5 5 0 0 0 0   0.5000000
3 0 0 3 0 0 0   0.0000000
4 1 0 0 9 0 0   0.1000000
6 0 0 0 1 0 0   1.0000000
8 0 0 0 1 0 0   1.0000000
```